# How to politely cancel signed contract because of another job offer before even starting at the company I signed with?

Tags: job-offer, resignation

I got another job offer from a different company a week after I signed the contract. I havent started working at the company though and I dont have a starting date yet. (Or if the orientation day is also the starting date then I'll be starting the day after tomorrow.)

Says in the contract that I need a month notice.

Any tips on what to say to my employer? I know I'll be ruining my reputation here but offer B seem to be much more promising than the one from company A.

Answer (score 3):

> Any tips on what to say to my employer?

If you are in the US, just say something like "I have decided to accept another job offer and I won't be joining [company]."

Say it as soon as you have a formally accepted offer from company B.

You will certainly be burning bridges and damaging your reputation, but you have indicated that you don't care. Even so, try to mitigate the damage to company A by letting them know as soon as you safely can.